# How to set multiple canvas in scroll viewer in wpf?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, scrollviewer

I want to set an image in a canvas control and have 20 canvases that I am creating by using a loop. The problem is that when I want to add all those canvas items in to a scroll viewer it does not work. Here is my code:

```
private void CreateAndShowCanvas()
{
    List<Canvas> list = new List<Canvas>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {


        Canvas myCanvas1 = new Canvas();
        myCanvas1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        myCanvas1.Height = 235;
        myCanvas1.Width = 626;
        //Canvas.SetZIndex(myCanvas1, 4);
        Image MainImage = new Image();
        MainImage.Width = 275;
        MainImage.Height = 235;
        BitmapImage mi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("select_1.png", UriKind.Relative));
        MainImage.Source = mi;
        Canvas.SetTop(MainImage, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(MainImage, 0);
        myCanvas1.Children.Add(MainImage);

        Image SeparatorImage = new Image();
        BitmapImage si = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Sentre Seprator.png", UriKind.Relative));
        SeparatorImage.Height = 270;
        SeparatorImage.Source = si;
        Canvas.SetTop(SeparatorImage, -5);
        Canvas.SetLeft(SeparatorImage, 310);
        myCanvas1.Children.Add(SeparatorImage);
        Image SecondImage = new Image();
        SecondImage.Width = 275;
        SecondImage.Height = 235;
        BitmapImage sci = new BitmapImage(new Uri("select_2.png", UriKind.Relative));
        SecondImage.Source = sci;
        Canvas.SetTop(SecondImage, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(SecondImage, 350);
        myCanvas1.Children.Add(SecondImage);
        list.Add(myCanvas1); 
    }

    scv.Content = list;
 }
```

and in XML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Name="scv" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="60,40,59,46" Opacity="99" Background="Transparent" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and when I run it, it only shows ("Collection"). Please help me out, thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you developing for WPF or Windows Phone 7? These are not the same! If I look at your code (Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"), I'm sure you mean WPF and not WP7...

Answer (score 0):

A [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx) can hold just a single child, so you need another panel type like a Grid or StackPanel which holds your canvases.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Name="scv" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="60,40,59,46" Opacity="99" Background="Transparent">
        <StackPanel Name="stp" />
    </ScrollViewer>    
</Grid>
```

Add canvases to stp instead.

Answer (score 0):

Should you not just be using a ListBox with an ItemTemplate that has Canvases inside it instead? There must be an easier way to do whatever you are trying to achieve than creating 20 canvases manually.

[Here's some reading to do with ListBoxes](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-listbox-answers-to-popular-questions).